# Quasar hot reloading issue

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

Hi I am using Quasar CLI with latest Quasar downloaded yesterday in Windows 10. I have some issues with hot reloading highlighted here: https://www.loom.com/share/3137f7ac86974af78a222a207b7c375e, what is the problem?

Comment: This is probably best logged in the github repo for quasar - they may then send you to webpack. Good luck

Comment: Same problem on android or iOS phone.

Comment: have you tried this? https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/quasar-config-file#docker-and-wsl-issues-with-hmr

Answer (score 0):

So in my case after connecting with Safari to Developer and triggering the problem.

The vendor.js and app.js are loading from wrong URL path such as "account/vendor.js" when it should be "vendor.js".

The index.html should put a / before these perhaps.
Could be due to using routing without the # symbol?

quasar.conf.js has this in the build options.
`vueRouterMode: 'history', // available values: 'hash', 'history'`

But with the index.html that I can see generated it puts the url as js/app.js and js/vendor.js...

Fix for me was to set these in the devServer and build in quasar.conf.js
It's probably appBase that "fixed it". but this could break other things I suppose depending on how the urls are structured.

```
// Full list of options: https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js#Property%3A-devServer
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true
   // ...
},


// Full list of options: https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js#Property%3A-build
build: {
  appBase: '/',
  publicPath: '/',
  vueRouterBase: '/',
  vueRouterMode: 'history', // available values: 'hash', 'history'
  // ...
}
```